# Updating the weights in a 2-layer neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, biological-neural-network

I am trying to simulate a XOR gate using a neural network similar to this:

[image]

Now I understand that each neuron has certain number of weights and a bias. I am using a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) to determine whether a neuron should fire or not in each state (since this uses a sigmoid rather than a step function, I use firing in a loose sense as it actually spits out real values).

I successfully ran the simulation for feed-forwarding part, and now I want to use the [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) algorithm to update the weights and train the model. The question is, for each value of `x1` and `x2` there is a separate result (4 different combinations in total) and under different input pairs, separate error distances (the difference between the desired output and the actual result) could be be computed and subsequently a different set of weight updates will eventually be achieved. This means we would get 4 different sets of weight updates for each separate input pairs by using backpropagation.

How should we decide about the right weight updates?

Say we repeat the back propagation for a single input pair until we converge, but what if we would converge to a different set of weights if we choose another pair of inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I understand that each neuron has certain weights. I am using a sigmoid function to determine a neuron should fire or not in each state.

You do not really "decide" this, typical MLP do not "fire", they output real values. There are neural networks which actually fire (like RBMs) but this is a completely different model.

> This means we would get 4 different sets of weight updates for each input pairs by using back propagation.

This is actually **a feature**. Lets start from the beggining. You try to minimize some loss function on your whole training set (in your case - 4 samples), which is of form:

```
L(theta) = SUM_i l(f(x_i), y_i)
```

where `l` is some loss function, f(x_i) is your current prediction and y_i true value. You do this by gradient descent, thus you try to compute the gradient of L and go against it

```
grad L(theta) = grad SUM_i l(f(x_i), y_i) = SUM_i grad l(f(x_i), y_i)
```

what you now call "a single update" is `grad l(f(x_i) y_i)` for a single training pair `(x_i, y_i)`. Usually you would not use this, but instead you would **sum** (or taken average) of updates across **whole dataset**, as this is your true gradient. Howver, in practise this might be computationaly not feasible (training set is usualy quite large), furthermore, it has been shown empirically that more "noise" in training is usually better. Thus another learning technique emerged, called **stochastic gradient descent**, which, in short words, shows that under some light assumptions (like additive loss function etc.) you can actually do your "small updates" independently, and you will still converge to local minima! In other words - you can do your updates "point-wise" in random order and you will still learn. Will it be always the same solution? No. But this is also true for computing whole gradient - optimization of non-convex functions is nearly always non-deterministic (you find **some local solution**, not global one).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am a beginner, so excuse my ignorance. Specifically in the case of this simple XOR gate (as a baseline method), should I take the average of all the updated weights of a node in each round of backpropogation on the dataset?

Comment: as described in detail in the answer: you can do both, you can take an average of these four updates, or you can update using single point, then calculate error for next (with updated weights) and update using it, and so on. First is known as **gradient descent** and second as **stochastic gradient descent**.

Comment: Can you explain more about why this is true:
'Usually you would not use this, but instead you would sum (or taken average) of updates across whole dataset'

Comment: What I meant in this sentence is that such gradient **is not** a valid gradient of the function being minimised. It can be shown to be its unbiased estimator of really high variance (under some assumptions on l). That's it, in practise one can do many things "in between" (thus mini-batch updates etc.) to benefit from both extremes.